# printing the command using environment variables in shell script not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo, azure-cli

I have a following requirement of running the azure cli commands in a bash script file, for which i have created two script files as below

1. to set the environment  (environment.sh)

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo "setting environment"
   export az_resource_group="test-group"
   echo "resource group is $az_resource_group"
   export az_source_server="test-server"
   echo "source_server is $az_source_server"
   export az_recovery_server="test-recovery-server"
   echo "recovery-server is$az_recovery_server"
   export az_restore_time="2020-07-27T12:52:21.000Z"
   echo "restore point in time is $az_restore_time"
   ```
2. the actual script file to run azure cli commands (azurecommands.sh)

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   resource_group=$az_resource_group
   recovery_server=$az_recovery_server
   source_server=$az_source_server
   restore_time=$az_restore_time
   echo "restoring postgresql database"
   echo "az postgres server restore -g $resource_group --restore-point-in-time $restore_time  -s $source_server -n $recovery_server"
   ```

the above az command works properly when run individually or using arguments in bash, but if i use **environment variables** the command itself does not form correctly. so i decided to print it so that i can verify what is command that is being formed.

To my surprise the output is `-n test-recovery-server 2020-07-27T12:52:21.000Z`
while my expected output is `az postgres server restore -g test-group --restore-point-in-time -s test-server -n test-recovery-server` .

I'm also making sure to run environment.sh file as follows:

```
source environment.sh
```

**How can echo not print the correct command?** is there something with the way i use environmental variables? if so please suggest me some other approach, because these commands need to be automated.

Comment: Have you made sure there are no carriage returns in your environment variables?

Comment: Instead with source, run the first script with `. ./environment.sh` and see if it helps.

Comment: Using `xtrace` -- as in, `bash -x yourscript` -- is a good place to start.

Comment: By the way, `/bin/sh` is not bash. Tag your questions `sh`, not `bash`, if it's the shell you mean to ask about. (Even if your OS uses bash for `sh`, it runs in a different mode without all features available when started under that name; if you want all bash features to be available, use `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: ...also, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. At least after you take out the `echo`, you'll have some bugs related to lack of quoting. (Part of why `set -x` is a better way to debug than `echo` is that it reflects your command arguments accurately -- `echo "first argument" "second argument"` looks exactly like `echo "first argument second argument"`, even though they're entirely different).

Comment: (And as Marko alludes to, `source` is one of the things that's guaranteed to work with `bash` but not with `sh`; with a baseline-POSIX version of `sh`, the guaranteed-available equivalent to `source` is the command named `.`).

Comment: What is the output of `azurecommands.sh | tr -d '\r' ` ?

Comment: As you are echoing string literals that you don't see, this is what might be happening: `r=$'\rD E F'; echo "A B C $r"` (backspaces work too), you are overwriting the output.

Comment: I'm betting one or both of your files have DOS/WIndows line endings, which have a carriage return at the end of each line. This'll add the carriage returns to your variables, and cause great confusion. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: add `.` to source the script. `. ./az.sh`

Comment: Thank you all for the help . @GordonDavisson . This link helped me. There were DOS/Windows line endings. i converted them to unix endings using : https://support.nesi.org.nz/hc/en-gb/articles/218032857-Converting-from-Windows-style-to-UNIX-style-line-endings#:~:text=To%20write%20your%20file%20in,with%20UNIX%2Dstyle%20line%20endings.
Appreciate the help :)

Comment: If you solve the issue yourself please add an answer to show it. Maybe other communities are looking for it.

Comment: Do you solve the problem? Or what do you want right now?